# How do I link to another folder on windows in my htdocs?

Tags: windows, apache

on my local website i would like to the /web directory point to a folder on my windows box. I have tried putting a shortcut there and it failed. I tried creating an alias in my httpd.conf and i get a 403 http error. Im out of ideas!

Comment: Try http://www.serverfault.com ...

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error means that for some reason the server process doesn't have permission to access that folder, but it looks like you're probably doing that alias correctly.

Just making sure, everything is entirely within windows?  If it was linux pointing to windows, you could `mount --bind` it somewhere, or chmod it to fix the permissions issue.

Comment: yes it pure windows! Is there a way to give apache access to the folder? i mean i can give SYSTEM, USERS, and generic things like that access but can i say HTTPD or something?